# error from debugger :error launching remote program

Tags: iphone

I am getting this error while running my app on the device.I have installed the distribution provisioning profile.

error from debugger :error launching remote program: failed to get the task from process 1637

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I came across this question while searching for an answer myself. I figured my problem was I was trying to launch and debug my app from xCode using the Ad-hoc provision rather than the developer 'Debug' provision. xCode would build and copy the app to the device but wouldn't debug.

I just changed the Active Configuration to Debug and the problem was solved. A silly mistake really.

Comment: This worked for me as well, though I didn't have a Development provisioning profile set up yet. A quick trip to the Organizer to register my device did the trick though.

Answer (score 2):

I have two suggestions:

**1)**  Quit simulator and xcode completely.  Then start back up.

**2)**  If you can run other projects OK, but not this particular project, it could be something wrong with your projectname.xcodeproj folder.

I spent hours trying to fix a similar problem.  I started picking apart changes from subversion and was "diffing" each and every file to find a "breaking change".  Finally, I just deleted the entire folder and then restored it from SCM and everything was fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Quit xcode and restart again works for me...