# Xcode error starting executable project

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I searched 5 hours solution, and I can't find it. Please help me. I uploaded my app yesterday to AppStore and I want to make an update. I made some changes in code and try to Run the new app with the Distribute scheme.

I got

```
Error Starting Executable "myApp"
Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 5047.
```

Solutions on forums are not working for me. What can I do?

Comment: What "Solutions on forums" have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988135/error-from-debugger-error-launching-remote-program (has good solution)

Answer (score 10):

Make sure you are not running the myApp with the distribution certificate because that will not work. Did you do a "Build - Clean" before testing ?

Answer (score 6):

You need to follow these steps:

1. If you are using xcode 4 then select your Project from left panel of xcode.
2. in info tab make sure that you have selected debug as command-line build to use
3. in build settings tab, search for code signing identity, if you have adhoc, debug, release, distribution profiles, then please make sure that you have developer provisioning certificate for adhoc,debug profiles.
4. now click on targets, in build settings tab, search for code signing identity. If you have adhoc,debug, release,distribution profiles, then please make sure that you have developer provisioning certificate for adhoc and debug profiles. Also, in code signing entitlements, do not include the entitlements for adhoc as well as for debug.
5. delete your build from your project folder.
6. restart  xcode.
7. run the app on the device. You will be able to debug from the device.
   Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm forgetting the exact steps, but make a 'zip' of your release build binary and manually upload that to itunesconnect.  Using the zip approach, just seems to eliminate a host of headaches, especially when trying to update the binary.

Answer (score 0):

Werner's response eventually worked for me. I ran into this issue after making adjustments to my app for ad hoc distribution (Testflight).

I could also minimize the disruption between Testflight and on-device debugging by simply changing one setting back-and-forth.  That is, during on-device testing:

1. Click your project in the Project Navigator
2. Re-select under 'Project' on the left side
3. Select the 'Build Settings' tab
4. Scroll down to the 'Code Signing' section
5. Reset your code-signing identity to 'iPhone Developer' (make sure the profile uses the same -- or wildcard * -- application identifier (in grey text))

For Testflight distros, I changed the identity back to a profile I carefully name 'Testflight'.

Another thing I found helpful was to use the application identifier as the name (without the dots) for the App ID in the Provisioning profile (to avoid confusion, that's developer.apple.com) .  Then you can see the differences in xcode between the two standard profiles, the automated one from xcode, and the one you actually want to use right now.